# Establishing birthplace of Heinrich Oldag in Silesia?

Tags: 19th-century, vital-records, poland, silesia

I am trying to find more information about Hans Heinrich Rudolf Oldag and Ernestine Pauline Friederike Hampel, the parents of Anna Minna Martha Oldag (born 10 Oct 1866 in Warmbrunn, Silesia, now Cieplice Śląskie, Poland).

In particular, I am trying to establish whether he was born in Techin, Lauenburg, in September 1828. It seems a long distance to travel.

I know that the parents of Anna Oldag died within a short time of each other (possibly on the same day, but most likely no more than a week apart) some time between 1868 and 1875.

I am hoping that there might still a marriage record, or death records, or perhaps grave markers in Poland. Short of traveling there myself, what other resources might there be?

Comment: A note about traveling...our ancestors moved around a lot more than we might think.  This was especially true once trains came into place, but they also moved a lot before that.

Comment: If you establish the birthplace of Heinrich in this question then doing the same for his wife may flow from there. If not then feel free to ask about her birthplace in a separate question that links back to this one.

Comment: What leads you to suspect that Hans might have been born in Techin (now in Mecklenburg-Vorpommern)?

Comment: There is some family lore that Anna Oldag's grandparents traveled to Australia. I found their name (Heinrich Hampel, wife and three children) on a ship's manifest, and the name "Heinrich Oldag, Techin, Lauenburg" appeared on the same page. On the other hand, there seems solid evidence (her gravestone), that Anna Oldag was born in Silesia in 1866. I am trying any avenues I can think of to nail down her movements and the possibility that she met her future husband in transit to Australia. (Still don't know how she got back to Germany, though.) A marriage record in Silesia would be swell!